# Sankey with Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, sankey-diagram

In this Senkey are two Inputs: K and S, three Outputs: H,F and Sp and the Rest: x

The Inputs shall come from the left Side, the Outputs go to the right Side.
The Rest shall go to the Top.

```
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = [10,10])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set(yticklabels=[],xticklabels=[])
ax.text(-10,10, "xxx")

Sankey(ax=ax,  flows = [ 20400,3000,-19900,-400,-2300,800],
              labels = ['K',   'S', 'H',    'F', 'Sp', 'x'],
        orientations = [ 1,    -1,   1,      0,  -1,  -1 ],
scale=1, margin=100,  trunklength=1.0).finish()

plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

I played a lot with the orientations, but nothing works or looks nice.
And, it there a way to set different colors for every arrow?

Comment: Try `scale=1e-5, margin=1,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scale` of the Sankey should be such that input-flow times scale is about 1.0 and output-flow times scale is about -1.0  ([see docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/sankey_api.html)). Therefore, about 1/25000 is a good starting point for experimentation. The `margin` should be a small number, maybe around 1, or leave it out. I think the only way to have individual colors, is to chain multiple Sankeys together (with `add`), but that's probably not what you want. Use `plt.axis("off")` to suppress the axes completely.

My test code:

```py
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = [10,10])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

Sankey(ax=ax,  flows = [ 20400,3000,-19900,-400,-2300,-800],
              labels = ['K',   'S', 'H',   'F', 'Sp',  'x'],
        orientations = [ 1,    -1,   1,     0,   -1,   -1 ],
        scale=1/25000, trunklength=1,
        edgecolor = '#099368', facecolor = '#099368'
      ).finish()
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Generated Sankey: [image: The generated Sankey plot]

Comment: Thank you, there was a missing "-" for the 800 in my code

Comment: I updated the code and image with this new value. It looks nicer with inputs and outputs having equal flow.

Answer (score 0):

With different Colors

```
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

plt.rc('font', family = 'serif')
plt.rcParams['font.size']  = 10
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = "Linux Libertine"

fig    = plt.figure(figsize = [6,4], dpi = 330)
ax     = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,)
s      = Sankey(ax = ax, scale = 1/40000, unit = 'kg', gap = .4, shoulder = 0.05,)

s.add(
    flows        = [3000,     20700,   -23700,], 
    orientations = [ 1,       1,       0, ],
    labels       = ["S Value", "K Value", None, ],
    trunklength = 1, pathlengths = 0.4, edgecolor = '#000000', facecolor = 'darkgreen', 
    lw = 0.5,
)

s.add(
    flows        = [23700,  -800,  -2400,     -20500],
    orientations = [0,       1,    -1,         0], 
    labels       = [None,   "U Value", "Sp Value",  None],
    trunklength=1.5, pathlengths=0.5, edgecolor = '#000000', facecolor = 'grey',
    prior = 0, connect = (2,0), lw = 0.5,
    )

s.add(
    flows        = [20500,  -20000,    -500],
    orientations = [0,      -1,        -1],
    labels       = [None,   "H Value",  "F Value"],
    trunklength =1, pathlengths = 0.5, edgecolor = '#000000', facecolor = 'darkred',
    prior = 1, connect = (3,0), lw = 0.5,
)

diagrams = s.finish() 

for d in diagrams:
    for t in d.texts:
        t.set_horizontalalignment('left')


diagrams[0].texts[0].set_position(xy = [-0.58,  0.9,]) # S 
diagrams[0].texts[1].set_position(xy = [-1.5,   0.9,]) # K 
diagrams[2].texts[1].set_position(xy = [ 2.35, -1.2,]) # H 
diagrams[2].texts[2].set_position(xy = [ 1.75, -1.2,]) # F 
diagrams[1].texts[2].set_position(xy = [ 0.7,  -1.2])  # Sp
diagrams[1].texts[1].set_position(xy = [ 0.7,   0.9,]) # U 

# print(diagrams[0].texts[0])
# print(diagrams[0].texts[1])
# print(diagrams[1].texts[0])
# print(diagrams[1].texts[1])
# print(diagrams[1].texts[2])
# print(diagrams[2].texts[0])
# print(diagrams[2].texts[1]) 
# print(diagrams[2].texts[2])

plt.axis("off") 
plt.show()
```

[image]