# Sankey with Matplotlib Positions of Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, sankey-diagram

After this: 
[Sankey with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895137/sankey-with-matplotlib)
I made this Code:

```
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams


## Plotten
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{underscore}') 
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 18
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = "Linux Libertine"

fig = plt.figure(figsize = [10,10], dpi=330)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,)

Sankey(ax=ax,  flows = [ 20400,3000,-19900,-400,-2300,-800],
              labels = ['Value K',   'Value S', 'Value H',   'Value F', 'Value Sp', 'uncertainty'],
        orientations = [ 1,    1,   -1,     -1,   0,  1 ],
        scale=1/40000, trunklength=1, unit = 'kg', pathlengths=0.5, gap=.5, 
        edgecolor = '#000000', facecolor = 'grey'
      ).finish()
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

With this result:[image]

How do I move the Labels (or Values) out of the Graph?

And is there a way to get a "." in the Values as a thousands separator like 20.400kg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got it

```
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

plt.rc('font', family = 'serif')
plt.rcParams['font.size']  = 10
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = "Linux Libertine"

fig    = plt.figure(figsize = [6,4], dpi=330)
ax     = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,)
sankey = Sankey(ax=ax, scale=1/40000, unit = 'kg',gap=.9,)

sankey.add(flows = [ 20400,3000,-19900,-400,-2300,-800],
              labels = ['Value K',   'Value S', 'Value H',   'Value F', 'Value Sp', 'uncertainty'],
        orientations = [ 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1 ],
         trunklength = 1, pathlengths = 0.5, edgecolor = '#000000', facecolor = 'grey')
diagrams = sankey.finish() 

print(diagrams[0].texts[0])
print(diagrams[0].texts[1])
print(diagrams[0].texts[2])
print(diagrams[0].texts[3])
print(diagrams[0].texts[4])
print(diagrams[0].texts[5]) 

diagrams[0].texts[0].set_position(xy=[-0.756,   1])    # K 
diagrams[0].texts[1].set_position(xy=[-1.955,   1])    # S 
diagrams[0].texts[2].set_position(xy=[ 1.6625, -1.2])  # H 
diagrams[0].texts[3].set_position(xy=[ 0.506,  -1])    # F 
diagrams[0].texts[4].set_position(xy=[ 1.5,     0.45]) # Sp 
diagrams[0].texts[5].set_position(xy=[ 0.5,     1])    # U 

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]